How to add additional params to authentication query with ITfoxtec.Identity.Saml2
I inherited an app that is using ITfoxtec.Identity.Saml2 to authenticate with an identity/oidc provider using SAML 2.0.
I haven't been able to figure out how to configure and send additional params when authenticating with the identity provider. Any help or pointers appreciated, tyia
Our provider requires us to send two params, PartnerSpID and an ACS index.  e.g.
https://my.oid.provider.com/idp/provider.saml2?partnerspid=abc&acsidx=1
The app is configuring SAML Auth with ITfoxtec SAML library like:
IServiceCollection services = ...

services.AddRazorPages();
services.Configure<Saml2Configuration>(Configuration.GetSection("SamlAuth"));

services.Configure<Saml2Configuration>(saml2Configuration =>
{
    saml2Configuration.AllowedAudienceUris.Add(saml2Configuration.Issuer);

    var entityDescriptor = new EntityDescriptor();
    entityDescriptor.ReadIdPSsoDescriptorFromUrl(new Uri(Configuration["SamlAuth:IdPMetadata"]));

    if (entityDescriptor.IdPSsoDescriptor != null)
    {
        saml2Configuration.SingleSignOnDestination = entityDescriptor.IdPSsoDescriptor.SingleSignOnServices.First().Location;
        saml2Configuration.SignatureValidationCertificates.AddRange(entityDescriptor.IdPSsoDescriptor.SigningCertificates);
    }
    else
    {
        // fail fast...
    }
});

services.AddSaml2();


Parameters in the URL are after the question mark and are separated by an ampersand.

You can add parameters when setting the SingleSignOnDestination
Uri postBinding = new Uri("urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-POST");
var uri = new Uri(entityDescriptor.IdPSsoDescriptor.SingleSignOnServices
    .Single(b => b.Binding == postBinding).Location.ToString() + "?partnerspid=abc&acsidx=1");
saml2Configuration.SingleSignOnDestination = uri;

for redirect binding, this works as expected and the SAMLRequest etc parameters get appended.
for postbinding the additional parameter will be passed as url params, not as post params
